# How can I disambiguate the following rules?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am having trouble with a *no viable alternative at input `sqr(`* with the following rules.

```
function_invocation : ID LPAREN term (',' term)* RPAREN ;

function_signature : ID LPAREN ID (',' ID)* RPAREN ;

term : function_invocation #functionTerm
     | number              #numberTerm
     | string              #stringTerm
     | ID                  #idTerm
     ;

 ID : ('a'..'z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
```

I use `function_signature` in other rules where I only want `ID` to be valid such as:

```
function_definition : function_signature '=>' expression (','NL expression)* '.'NL ;
```

should parse:

```
sqr(x) => x * x,
          x + 1.
```

And I use `function_invocation` where I want to allow more than just `ID`.

```
function_assignment : ID '=>' function_invocation ;
```

should parse:

```
z = sqr(3)
```

The problem is that `ID` is a valid `term`.

#### How do I tell ANTLR4 tell the different between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it so `function_signature` can only be used when inside a `function_definition`. In other words, drop that rule altogether, and write

```
function_definition : ID '(' ID (',' ID)* ')' '=>' expression (',' NL expression)* '.' NL ;
```

This way, the `=>` terminal can be used to avoid the ambiguity. Alternatively, just put the `=>` terminal in the `function_signature`:

```
function_signature : ID '(' ID (',' ID)* ')' '=>' ;
function_definition : function_signature expression (',' NL expression)* '.' NL ;
```

Of course, I'm assuming here there's no other place in your grammar that allows a `function_invocation` followed by a `=>`, but that would probably make the whole language ambiguous.